# Custom keybinding in vim's insert mode is not working

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I would like to add ctrl+s as a custom keybind that lets me save the current vim document. Here is what I have on my .gvimrc file:

```
nnoremap <C-s> <Esc>:w<CR> 
vnoremap <C-s> <Esc>:w<CR>
inoremap <C-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a
```

The first two lines work fine (which correspond to saving in normal mode and saving in visual mode). However, the third line does not work. I want ctrl+s in insert mode to correspond to:

1. escape key (to go to normal mode)
2. `:w` to save the vim document
3. type "a" to come back to insert mode.

However, when I type ctrl+s in insert mode, it displays "^S" and does not actually save the document.

Is there a way to get around this?

OS: Arch Linux with i3 window manager.

Comment: Probably your terminal's fault. What terminal do you have?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I use gvim (gui for vim), it doesn't use a terminal. That code works for me too - I can use ctrl+s to save in both normal mode and visual mode. But I want to do that in insert mode as well (3rd line of my code). I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: Can you reproduce that behaviour without loading any configuration?

Comment: @romainl I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: `echo "inoremap <C-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a" > tmprc && vim -u tmprc`. Works for me on both termite as well as alacritty. i3 on Arch Linux.

Comment: @GA90 I mean that you should test without any configuration (no `.vimrc`, no `.gvimrc`). If it still happens, then it probably is a Vim bug that's worth reporting to the issue tracker or mailing list. If it doesn't happen, then the fault is very likely to be somewhere in your config and you can start debugging it on your own until you find the culprit. You can use @Mateen Ulhaq's with `gvim` instead of `vim`.

Comment: Ctrl+S is a bit of an unfortunate combo. On my terminal (iTerm 2 on OS X), the other two also don't work. I can't even use Ctrl+V -> Ctrl+S to type the character, the Ctrl+S will just not be registered. Most likely it's because of the Ctrl+S / Ctrl+Q default behaviour (stop updates to the terminal / restore updates to the terminal)